# GIT Publisher Plugin

Tags: git, jenkins

I have been trying to use the GIT Publisher plugin. I am making a change to one of my branches in Bitbucket. What i want is to see the committed changes made in that branch reflect in one of the tags via Jenkins.

To achieve this, i created a job in Jenkins with parameterized build on the branch name. I entered repo url, credentials and name as bitbucket. Then i added one build step ---> Execute shell for checking out repo master.
Next i entered details in plugin making sure that remote name is Bitbucket only. 
Upon execution, i see that job fails, but i see a Tag created in bitbucket which is a replica of master but not of the branch in which i actually made the change. 
If i change shell command from master to branch name, job still does the same thing as above.

How to enter details which actually create a tag in Bitbucket and reflect changes that i made in a particular branch.

Thanks.